# Executing a code block (DO) using pg promise

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

I'm using pg promise and I can't seem to find anywhere in the documentation about if I'm able to execute a DO block. A short example of what I'm trying to do looks like:

```
public async update(oldDate, newDate) {
   try {
      const query = `DO $$
      DECLARE
      users record;
      BEGIN
      FOR users in (
         SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE type = 'standard'
      )
      LOOP
      INSERT INTO standard_accounts(id, name) VALUES('some id', 'some name');
      END LOOP
      END$$`;

      await pgPromise.any(query);
   } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('error');
   }
}
```

I'm relatively new to using it so I'm unsure if I can even use this approach or if I'll have to find another one. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: You really don't need pl/pgsql or loops or do blocks for this. Just `INSERT INTO standard_accounts(id, name) SELECT 'some id', 'some name' FROM accounts WHERE type = 'standard';`

Comment: @SkinnyBetas You forgot to include what issue you are having executing it.